How to hide or remove anchor tag from react paginate
I am using react-paginate package in Next js website. I have 2 pagination components. In the first pagination component I have generated links which is good. but in the second pagination component I don't want to generate links. I only need the page count to call API. So, far everything is working as expected but I have checked validator w3 website and it was showing this error and it is happening because of the 2nd component because it doesn't have any links.
Error: Element a is missing required attribute href.
page-item"><a rel="next" role="button" class="page-link" tabindex="0" aria-label="Page 2">2</a><

My question is, Is there any way to remove the a tag or replace it with a button tag?
